# What do the rainbow blocks mean?

Tags: tetris-axis

I was playing a World match on Tetris Axis, and noticed that sometimes, a block on one of my Tetriminos would be rainbow coloured. I never saw the blocks with the rainbow bits behave any differently, so that leaves me wondering - what was that for? Why did it happen?

Answer (score 1):

**Item Blocks** (The Rainbow-Color Blocks) will Provide you with a Item when Cleared, Press X to Use that Item, You can stock up to 3 Items.